# Jquery draggable + resizable causing issues, element doesn't stay within it's parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Here's the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hjtBA/

When you try to drag the element to the south-east corner and repeat doing so, you will notice the element is going out of bounds. I noticed this only occurs when the draggable and resizable plugins are being used together on one element.

How can this be resolved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the containment to parent on resizable also:

```
$(function(){
    $('#inner').resizable({
        containment: 'parent'        
    });
    $('#inner').draggable({
        containment: 'parent'        
    });    
});​
```

Here it is updated: http://jsfiddle.net/hjtBA/97/

Comment: Try dragging the element to the bottom right. and keep repeating so, don't resize the element. Right now it doesn't seem like a big deal. But check this out: http://elixia.biggo.org

Click on an image, click edit image and choose a new one. while in the cropping mode, drag the crop bottom right and see the annoying effect this has.